# Calculate recently modified Date Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

SharePoint Online.

```
Date Column A - Date when the value changed to X, 
Date Column B - Date when the value changed to Y,
```

How to create a calculated

```
Date Column C = Recent Modification or latest change in Column A Or Column B?
```

Answer (score 1):

Column C formula is

```
=IF([ColumnA]>[ColumnB], [ColumnA], [ColumnB])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this maybe what you are looking for but we completely need more information like "What you are really looking to accomplish;"

Try...
=IF([Modified]>[ColumnA], [Modified], IF([ColumnA]>[ColumnB], [ColumnA], [ColumnB]))

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does **not** record **when** a COLUMN value changed; if you need that you must create a Workflow and do the administration yourself

If you mean you want the maximum value of the 3 columns:

**DateA**  or  **DateB** or  **Modified** (SharePoints last registered anything-in-the-ITEM changed)

it is:

```
=MAX( [DateA] , [DateB] , [Modified] )
```

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List